# MongoDB. Почему при увеличении размера коллекции сильно увеличивается время вставки новых документов?

Tags: linux, база-данных, mongodb, администрирование

**MongoDB 3.2.1 | wiredTiger**

Вставляются новые документы.
Никаких условий или сложной выборки нет.

**Collection statistics:**

```
"count" : 149380522
"size" : 5582314593.0
"avgObjSize" : 37
"storageSize" : 12036964352.0
"capped" : false
"totalIndexSize" : 1537122304.0
```

**/etc/security/limits.d/99-mongodb.conf**

```
mongod          soft    fsize           unlimited
mongod          hard    fsize           unlimited
mongod          soft    cpu             unlimited
mongod          hard    cpu             unlimited
mongod          soft    as              unlimited
mongod          hard    as              unlimited
mongod          soft    nofile          65536
mongod          hard    nofile          65536
mongod          soft    nproc           65536
mongod          hard    nproc           65536
```

В выводе **dmesg** нет ничего бросающегося в глаза.

**mongostat:**

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes vsize  res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn                      time
*0    *0    217     *0       0   139|0     2.0   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1  136k    59k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:49+03:00
*0    *0    175     *0       0   109|0     0.7   29.4       1  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1  108k    50k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:50+03:00
*0    *0     43     *0       0    32|0     0.5   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1   29k    27k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:51+03:00
*0    *0     10     *0       0     7|0     0.6   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1    6k    20k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:52+03:00
*0    *0     28     *0       0    15|0     0.6   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1   14k    23k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:53+03:00
*0    *0      2     *0       0     1|0     0.6   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1  425b    18k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:54+03:00
*0    *0      1     *0       0     2|0     0.6   29.4       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1  368b    18k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:55+03:00
*0    *0     17     *0       0    14|0     0.6   29.5       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1   11k    21k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:56+03:00
*0    *0     11     *0       0    10|0     0.6   29.5       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1    8k    20k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:57+03:00
*0    *0      4     *0       0     2|0     0.6   29.5       0  2.6G 2.3G   0|0   0|1    2k    18k    6 2016-02-15T14:45:58+03:00
```

**top:**

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2222 mongod    20   0 4200976 3,692g   6664 S   3,3 23,9   0:50.26 mongod
```

Сильные задержки на вставку начались примерно от 140 миллионов документов.
Если создать новую коллекцию и записывать в нее, то все работает как надо.
Записывается примерно по 300 документов в секунду.

**Пример вставки документа (golang + labix.org/mgo):**

```
if _, err := c.UpsertId(bson.ObjectIdHex("xxxxxxx"), bson.M{
 "$set": bson.M{"field": "string"},
}); err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Собственно, как исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Время вставки документов, скорее всего, упирается в перестройку индексов коллекции. Можете попробовать включить создание индексов в фоновом режиме или удалить неиспользуемые индексы. Если и это не поможет, то стоит задуматься об использовании шардинга.